# Nurikabe: A Gentle Walk in the Hall of Giants

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This puzzle is a [Nurikabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe_(puzzle)) that is designed to be a gentle introduction to the genre, with a learning curve of progressively harder deductions. It is encouraged for first-time solvers and those who want to try learning the deductions necessary to solve these kinds of puzzles. It's also my first grid-deduction puzzle - I hope you enjoy!

Rules of a Nurikabe (paraphrased from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89554/nurikabe-sixes)):

> This is a Nurikabe puzzle. The goal is to paint some cells black so that the resulting grid satisfies the rules of Nurikabe:
>
> - Numbered cells are white. (Think of them as "islands.")
> - White cells are divided into regions, all of which contain exactly one number. The number indicates how many white cells there are in that region.
> - Regions of white cells *cannot be adjacent* to one another, but they *can* touch at a corner.
> - Black cells must all be orthogonally connected. (Think of them as "oceans.")
> - There are no groups of black "ocean" cells that form a 2×2 square anywhere in the grid.

Now, here's the puzzle:

[image: Nurikabe grid]

[And here is the puzz.link solver,](https://puzz.link/p?nurikabe/10/10/6m6k2g2l2p2v1g3g1i2w2n3h2co) which lets you solve it online. I also made sure the image was MS Paint compatible.

*(Beta-solved and tested by the incomparable crown, @bobble - thank you!)*

Comment: This is the first time I've come across this type of puzzle - thanks for the introduction!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting off by filling the 'easy' deductions with the 1s and 2s:

> [image]

Next, we have to consider reachability:

> We need to stretch the upper-left 6 as far as possible to avoid a 2×2, and then we can resolve the nearby 3 as well.
>  [image]

Now, an interesting deduction appears:

> [image]
>  We can't have this red box fully shaded. But only *one* of those cells is reachable -- the top-right one, by the 6 clue. That will stretch out the 6 as much as possible, too.
>
>  [image]

Next,

> look at the newly-created dot near the bottom. If it's taken by the 12, then the 3 must go downwards -- and now the wall between the 12 and the 3 is trapped, without any way to connect to the rest of the wall.
>
>  So that must be part of the 3 instead.
>
>  [image]

And finally:

> The cell in row 5, column 9, must be shaded; if it's unshaded, then it must be taken by the 6, and that blocks off the top-right wall region. And with that, the puzzle is solved!
>
>  [image]

Comment: I just sat down for a cup of coffee after posting. I *just* sat down :p

Comment: @sciborg 'tis the power of deus