# Nurikabe: The Twisty Corridors

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This puzzle is a [Nurikabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe_(puzzle)). It is a little tougher than my previous one, which was designed for newer solvers, and it has a particularly squiggly solution that I found pleasing enough to post - hence the name! I hope you enjoy.

Rules of a Nurikabe (copied from [my previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106152/nurikabe-a-gentle-walk-in-the-hall-of-giants)):

> This is a Nurikabe puzzle. The goal is to paint some cells black so that the resulting grid satisfies the rules of Nurikabe:
>
> - Numbered cells are white. (Think of them as "islands.")
> - White cells are divided into regions, all of which contain exactly one number. The number indicates how many white cells there are in that region.
> - Regions of white cells cannot be adjacent to one another, but they can touch at a corner.
> - Black cells must all be orthogonally connected. (Think of them as "oceans.")
> - There are no groups of black "ocean" cells that form a 2×2 square anywhere in the grid.

Now, here is the puzzle:

[image]

And here is a [puzz.link solver](https://puzz.link/p?nurikabe/10/10/h4h4h3m1i7q2l3k2p5h1p3h1g3w1i1g1) for your solving convenience.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Solution**:

> [image]

---

New solver too! This is the first 'plain' nurikabe I've solved, and here's how to solve:

**STEP 1**:

> [image]
>
> Starting off just filling in the obvious clues

**STEP 2**:

> [image]
>
> The four top middle can only extend in one direction, and can be completed.

**STEP 3**:

> [image]
>
> Filling in all the 'unreachable' cells, and also noticing the five must extend diagonally to prevent a 2x2 bottom right

**STEP 4**:

> [image]
>
> The 3 bottom middle must extend at least one up to prevent a 2x2, and this lets us solve the 3 and the 5.

**STEP 5**:

> [image]
>
> The top right can be solved nice and easily now, and the rest is nearly complete! The 7 must also extend all the way round to prevent a 2x2.

**FINAL STEP**:

> [image]
>
> Finishing off the top left gives us the answer!

Comment: Beat me to it! Looks good to me :)

Comment: This is it, awesome job! :D