# Nurikabe: The Terrible Tower of Threes!

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction

This puzzle is a quick and fun little [Nurikabe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nurikabe_(puzzle)) that is very tall, because I am not. It's not particularly tough, but if you need a nice relaxing grid-deduction puzzle to calm your brain today, this should provide a good flow. I hope you enjoy!

Rules of a Nurikabe (paraphrased from [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89554/nurikabe-sixes)):

> This is a Nurikabe puzzle. The goal is to paint some cells black so that the resulting grid satisfies the rules of Nurikabe:
>
> - Numbered cells are white. (Think of them as "islands.")
> - White cells are divided into regions, all of which contain exactly one number. The number indicates how many white cells there are in that region.
> - Regions of white cells *cannot be adjacent* to one another, but they *can* touch at a corner.
> - Black cells must all be orthogonally connected. (Think of them as "oceans.")
> - There are no groups of black "ocean" cells that form a 2×2 square anywhere in the grid.

Now, here's the puzzle:

[image]

[And here is the puzz.link solver](https://puzz.link/p?nurikabe/8/18/o8n1k1h3k1j2l3g23z2o24g4l2h2x5i3k2l2j2g3i3j), which lets you solve it online.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Solution:

> [image]

---

Here’s how to solve:

1:

> [image]
>
> Filling in the simple clues, gives us a nice easy starting point

2:

> [image]
>
> A lot of the 2s can only go in one direction, and looking up top the 8 must extend to the right to prevent a square being formed.

3:

> [image]
>
> A lot of the black squares can now be joined together, as they must to prevent isolation. Most of the left is now solved.

4:

> [image]
>
> The top can now be completed by considering what squares must be part of the 8 and what must be black. The 3 can only go in one way to prevent squares being formed

From here, the solution can be found by working downwards! Nice puzzle!

Comment: Beautiful solution. I'm glad you enjoyed :)

Comment: @Sciborg might have been simple, but had a nice flowing solution path!! Also ignore my accidental half answer I posted earlier if you noticed, am on mobile and clicked submit instead of preview :P